# Method org/hibernate/cache/ehcache/EhCacheRegionFactory.start(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;Ljava/util/Map;)V is abstract

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I am trying to configure hibernate without using the *hibernate.cfg.xml* file and using annotations instead. It works fine until I activate the second level cache to access statistics like hit, fetch and miss count.
When I set the option *use_second_level_cache* to true I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class
> path resource
> [myPath/hibernate/config/HibernateConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method
> org/hibernate/cache/ehcache/EhCacheRegionFactory.start(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;Ljava/util/Map;)V
> is abstract

Here's the relevant configurations lines:

```
properties.put(USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, true);
properties.put(CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
```

and (part of) my pom:

```
 <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
  ...
 <!-- Hibernate Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I initially thought of a version issue or conflicting jars, but can't seem to spot the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What hibernate and ehcache versions do you use?

Comment: 5.2.10.Final - I updated the initial post

Comment: What [ehcache](https://www.ehcache.org/) version do you use?

Comment: the same as hibernate, 5.2.10-Final (see pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the project made the issue vanish.